# How two javascript parameter passing "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

```
<button type="button" aria-haspopup="dialog" aria-controls="a" onclick="openLayer($('#a'))"> button</button>

<div role="dialog" id="a"><"button type="button">close<"/button></div>

function openLayer(target){
    event.preventDefault();
    var backFocus = $("[aria-controls='"+target+"']");
    $(target).attr("tabindex", 0).attr("aria-hidden", false).show().focus();
    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == "27"){
            console.log(backFocus); // [obeject object]
            $(target).attr("tabindex", 1).attr("aria-hidden", true).hide().blur();
        }
    });
}
```

I want target passing this.

how to focus back "button" ?

Comment: show more code of context usage

Comment: @kHRYSTAL, update your question by including the code, do not post it here in the comments.

Comment: sorry. that my code

Comment: have a look to https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events

Comment: What "this" are you refering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction(myElement){
  console.log(myElement.id);
 console.log( myElement.getAttribute("a"));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(this)" id="text" a="secret">click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks ^^ :)
I'm Settle